# google spreadsheet: query in a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hy,
my question is:
I'm working with spreadsheet of google.
I'd like to insert query into a script.
Is it possible?

I need create a spreadsheet in which runs a query to create an effect "post card" (name of a people and salary in different years).

I rescue to do it in a cell for only a man:

```
 query(sheet1!1:100; "select I, J,K, G, sum(H), F, L where B contains """&A6&""" group by B,I, J, K, G, F, L ")
```

"""&A6&""" is a cell in which i put a name.

I need to do it for all my collegues (30) in a script.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I may well be misinterpreting your question, but say you had 30 entries in A6:A35 (with no blanks), you could return all data where column B contains any of those 30 names with:

`=QUERY(sheet1!1:100;"select I, J, K, G, sum(H), F, L where B matches '.*"&JOIN(".*|.*";A6:A35)&".*' group by B, I, J, K, G, F, L")`

Comment: ok this is a function of a spreadsheet. I wanto to do it in the script of the same spreadsheet. Thanks

Comment: i tried in a cell. It doesn't work. It gives an error: circular dependency detected.. I'don't kwon...

Comment: can you explanate code? I don't understand this '.*"&JOIN(".*|.*";A6:A35)&".*'. I know what a JOIN is. Thanks

Comment: "Circular dependency" - in what cell are you entering the formula? Re the JOIN spreadsheet function, it's essentially creating a regex pattern along the lines of '.*john.*|.*steven.*|.*mary.*' so the "matches" condition is met whenever one of those names appear in the column.

Comment: sorry my query now goes. it's so: =query(QUERY(Sheet1!1:100;"select B, E, count(I), sum(H) where B matches '.*"&JOIN(".*|.*";I83:I204)&".*' group by B, E");"select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 where Col2='2012' "). Now I have only one name for the year 2012 with all yours data! Thanks for help